# ArrayList partial integrating one List in another

Tags: arraylist, insert, comparator

I have a function that creates regular Objects of a same type and I cannot avoid that step.
When I use List.addAll(*) I will get many "Duplications" that are not equal in sense of Objectivity.

I have a very bad coded solution and want to ask if there could be a better or more effective one maybe with Java-Util-functions and defining a Comparator for that single intermezzo?

Here is my bad smell:

```
private void addPartial(List<SeMo_WikiArticle> allnewWiki, List<SeMo_WikiArticle> newWiki) {
    if(allnewWiki.isEmpty())
        allnewWiki.addAll(newWiki);
    else{
        for(SeMo_WikiArticle nn : newWiki){
            boolean allreadyIn = false;
            for(SeMo_WikiArticle oo : allnewWiki){
                if(nn.getID()==oo.getID())
                    allreadyIn= true;
            }
            if(!allreadyIn)
                allnewWiki.add(nn);
        }
    }

}
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add an override function of `equals()` into `class SeMo_WikiArticle` :

```
class SeMo_WikiArticle {
    // assuming this class has two properties below
    int id;
    String name;

    SeMo_WikiArticle(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // implement your own comparison policy
        // here is an example
        if (obj instanceof SeMo_WikiArticle) {
            SeMo_WikiArticle sw = (SeMo_WikiArticle)obj;
            if (this.id == sw.id && (this.name == sw.name || this.name.equals(sw.name))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

After that you can use `contains()` to judge if the list has already contains the specific object of `SeMo_WikiArticle`.

Here is the code:

```
private void addPartial(List<SeMo_WikiArticle> allnewWiki, List<SeMo_WikiArticle> newWiki) {
    for (SeMo_WikiArticle sw : newWiki) {
        if (!allnewWiki.contains(sw)) {
            allnewWiki.add(sw);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was my first thought, too. But I need the SeMo_WikiArticle.equals(Object obj)-Method allready for other (more important) purposis :( So if there whould exist a contains(sw, Comparator<SeMo_WikiArticle>) my problem would be solved ;)

Comment: @Oekel An important principle is that when you override `equals()`, it should function the same wherever it's called, not only for specific purpose. Because **this function** along with `hashCode()` is the basis of comparison system in java, and also affects the `Set` and `Map` classes to identify an object.